# Deleting char* after assigning it to a string variable

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

I have executed the below code and it works perfectly. Since it is about pointers, I just want to be sure. Though I'm sure that assigning char* to string makes a copy and even if I delete char*, string var is gonna keep the value.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    int main()
    {
        std::string testStr = "whats up ...";
        int strlen = testStr.length();
        char* newCharP = new char[strlen+1];
        memset(newCharP,'\0',strlen+1);
        memcpy(newCharP,testStr.c_str(),strlen);


        std::cout << "  :11111111   :   " << newCharP << "\n";
        std::string newStr = newCharP ;

        std::cout << "  2222222 : " << newStr << "\n";
        delete[] newCharP;
        newCharP = NULL;

        std::cout << "  3333333 : " << newStr << "\n";
    }
```

I'm just changing some code in my company project and char* are passed between functions in C++. The char* pointer has been copied to the string, but the char* is deleted in the end of the function. I couldn't find any specific reason for this. So I'm just deleting the char*, as soon as it is copied into a string. Would this make any problem ...?

P.S : I have already asked this question in Codereview , but I got suggestion to move it to SO. So i have flagged it for close there and posting the question here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no problem, as long as `newChar` points to a null-terminated string, and is not null itself.

`std::string` has constructor that allows an implicit construction from a `const char*`. It makes a copy of the character string represented by the input `const char *` so it works under the assumption that the `char*` is a null terminated string, since there is no other way to know how many characters to copy into the string's own data storage. Furthermore, a `NULL` pointer is actually disallowed by the standard.

Answer (score 12):

No, because `std::string` copies the contents of your `char*`, so you're free to delete it when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine, if you look at the constructors of `std::basic_string` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) you'll be able to deduce that `std::string` has two interesting constructors here:

```
(4) string(char const*,
           size_type count,
           Allocator const& alloc = Allocator() );

(5) string(char const* s,
           Allocator const& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Both perform a copy, and the first reads exactly `count` characters whilst the second reads up until it encounters a NUL-character.

---

That being said, I actively encourage you *not* to use dynamic allocation here. If you want a temporary buffer to play with, consider using `std::vector` instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string testStr = "whats up ...";
    unsigned strlen = testStr.length();

    std::vector<char> buffer(strlen+1);

    memset(&buffer[0],'\0',strlen+1);
    memcpy(&buffer[0], testStr.c_str(), strlen);

    std::cout << "  :11111111   :   " << &buffer[0] << "\n";

    std::string newStr(&buffer[0]);

    std::cout << "  2222222 : " << newStr << "\n";

    buffer.clear();

    std::cout << "  3333333 : " << newStr << "\n";
}
```

Note: both `vector` and `string` have range-constructors, to build them from a range of iterators, that I purposefully refrained from using to avoid confusion and you being overwhelmed. Just know that you could have used them to avoid calling `memcpy` and risking a buffer overflow though.

Comment: Thanks Matt, actually the char* is passed from another function. Like i said i'm working on some old code and i can't go on and change arguments in all function calls.Our Codebase is pretty large. And the delete for these char* are performed in many parts of the function,each executes once only,on some conditions. I didn't like the code duplication though, so i have simply copied the char* to string and deleted the char* in the beginning of function itself.

Comment: @ManikandarajS: Hum! I know your pain, I've had to work on some gloomy applications myself :( In that case, you are heading in the right direction by trying to limit the "infection" and adapting the code you have to work on so it gets better!